# Accessing bitsy using gremlin from a java application

Tags: graph, graph-databases, gremlin, bitsy

i have a java application which writes network state information into Bitsy. which seems to be working fine since i can retrieve the stored data within that thread.

I also have another class where i am trying to use gremlin to retrieve the vertices(as below).

```
GremlinPipeline pipe = new GremlinPipeline(mygraph.getVertices("type", "switch"));
for (Object o : pipe)
{
  System.out.println(o.toString());
}
```

Although when i look at the Bitsy database files which are supposed to contain information like below for a vertex:

```
V={"id":"23r977e8-b234-50f1-23n6-235435n3455","v":1,"s":"M","p":{"name":"test"}}#23jh4587
```

Instead all i see is a list

```
H=3#0021a605
L=2#00237762
L=9#0023783b
L=10#044b72d3
L=11#044b7311
.
.
```

and so on.

Could anyone tell me where i am wrong. btw i am using Bitsy 1.5.1 with gremlin-java-2.4.0.jar with eclipse kepler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `toString` on a graph element (`Vertex` or `Edge`) will not return a representation of  the data held by that element.  What is shows is dependent on the Blueprints implementation but typically shows the identifier for the element.  If you want all the properties you could use the [map](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/blob/2.5.0/gremlin-java/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/java/GremlinFluentPipeline.java#L729) step or maybe use the [ElementHelper](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/2.5.0/blueprints-core/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/util/ElementHelper.java#L148).